# Acumatica not allowing user to input special characters

Tags: acumatica

I need to keep users from entering special characters into a text field.  I don't know how to accomplish this.  I've tried something like this but it's not the right thing `[PXDBString(50, InputMask = "^[A-Za-z0-9]$")]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find your input mask options from the Acumatica help:

[Input Validation Options](https://help.acumatica.com/(W(1))/Wiki/ShowWiki.aspx?pageid=9b12bbba-a619-43e4-8335-11ffff13573b)

If you cannot get the regex working (I have not tried and I don't see any examples used by Acumatica) you could set the input like this:

```
[PXDBString(50, InputMask = "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA")]
```

Also make sure in the page you are using the `PXMaskEdit` control.

Taking it a step further if needed you could use a field updating event as needed to check or wash any non letters/numbers.

Comment: I think this is limited to a short character input right (field can take up to 50 characters)? when I put regular expression in the InputMask it is displayed as string in the field.

Comment: Are you using the PXMaskEdit control for the field in the page also?

Comment: Yes is see the same. Regex is input as the value when used as an InputMask. Using "...A..." will result in the correct entry preventing the user from keying in any non letter/number value.

Comment: I wasn't using PXMaskEdit.  I think I will use the FieldVerifying method in the BLC.  Thanks